# Calculating sampling weights when I have sampled from a known population

Tags: sampling

I have a very large data (100+ million records)and I am estimating a complex random coefficients model and I can only comfortably use a million or so records. Iam interested in details in time and space so I have sampled on these attributes so that each  space-time cell has 10 records. Consequently some cells are overrepresented compared to the population and some are underrepresented. I also have several other variables -all of them categorical and because I can compare the obtained sample with the know frequencies in the population I can evaluate the under and over representation  of these types too.

I want to use sampling weights to rebalance the sample as in the population on a number of attributes simultaneously. Can I use a model whether the dependent variable is in sample or not and predictor variables based on type to derive these weights?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How many attributes did you sample on? How many are going to be part of the model.?

Comment: I think I have at the minimum of  4 categories by 2 by 2  if I take interactions into account but this could increase considerably if I take into account time on a month by month bases as  a main effect it would be 12 months by 12 year. So if I took into account all of this it would be with interactions  4 * 2 *2 *12 * 12 - but I have a lot of records! Thanks for answering.

Comment: Describe the random coefficients model.  From what you've described so far, your sampling method would make difficult any analysis.  For example if you have  repeated observations on individuals, so that coefficients vary with individual,  I'd think that a valid sampling method would have to start with a sample of individuals.

Comment: I am quite comfortable with the problem as listed - the level 1 units are not repeatedly measured - they are however repeated measures of higher level units - but I think I know how to calculate higher level weights and how to use them. What i was looking for was help on the fixed effects ts and how to estimate suitable weights that will overcome the mis-representation of the level 1 units. Thank for taking the time to resdpond

Comment: What was the sampling design for the higher level units?

Comment: I have all the higher level units - there are 5 levels of them and they are all there. However the level 1 units have been sampled to a maximum number per week in each of the lowest higher level so that in some periods - the boom times - this represents a lower sampling ratio than in others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your question based on the information you've already provided. I don't see how these weights can be used in a random effects model, but that's not what you asked for.

1- Constructing sampling Weights

The cells in which you selected 10 observations each are known as   "sampling strata". You have 4 x 2 x 2 x 12 x 12 = 2,304 of them. Number  for convenience from $i = 1\ldots 2304$. You know $N_i$,
    the number of records in cell $i$.  Then the probability of
    selection for records  in cell $i$ is $f_i=\dfrac{10}{N_i}$, and the
    sampling weight is

$$
w_i = \frac{1}{f_i} =  \frac{N_i}{10}
$$

These are the "design" or "sampling" weights.

2-  Balancing on other categorical variables  known for the entire population.

The standard method for doing this is variously known as "raking", "ratio raking" or "sample balancing".  with the first common in the survey literature.  The technique is an application of interative proportional fitting (IPF). The commands take the design weights and alter them so them that the resulting weighted totals for categories match the known totals.

References:
L Anderson and R Fricker "Raking: an important and often overlooked survey analysis tool"
http://faculty.nps.edu/rdfricke/docs/RakingArticleV2.2.pdf

Battaglia, Michael P, David Izrael, David C Hoaglin, and Martin R Frankel. 2004. Tips and tricks for raking survey data (aka sample balancing). Abt Associates 4740-4744.

http://www.amstat.org/sections/srms/Proceedings/y2004/files/Jsm2004-000074.pdf

**Software:**

**SAS** macros

http://abtassociates.com/Expertise/Surveys-and-Data-Collection/Raking-Survey-Data-%28a-k-a--Sample-Balancing%29.aspx

**Stata**:

- **ipfraking** (Stas Kolenikov)   "findit ipfraking"
- **survgwt rake** (Nicholas Winter) "ssc install survwgt"

**R** package **survey** (Tom Lumley) https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful -on the use of weights in multilevel modelling see http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glimmix_examples23.htm

Comment: You're very welcome.  Since you've found the answer useful, please "accept" it.  And thanks for the SAS link;  I hadn't seen it and I like the simulation.  Stata has added similar survey weighting options to most of  its multilevel mixed effects commands see, e.g.. p. 21 of  http://www.stata.com/manuals14/memeglm.pdf.

Comment: And for more completion MLwiN also has this weighting facility :  http://www.bristol.ac.uk/media-library/sites/cmm/migrated/documents/weighting.pdf